# Property exists but "does not exist on this collection instance." happens

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

"Exception
Property [delivery_cycle] does not exist on this collection instance."
Error occured.

But the property exists as far as I can see.

How should I fix it?

here is log.

> local.DEBUG: :TEST_ABC: [{"Illuminate\Support\Collection":[{"id":80,"company_id":96,"plan_id":1,"start_ym":202107,"end_ym":null,"created_at":"2021-06-18 15:47:01","updated_at":"2021-06-18 15:47:01","deleted_at":null,"delivery_cycle":3,"delivery_time":2,}]}]

delivery_cycle:3
is displayed.

my code

```
        $contracts = \DB::table('company_contracts')->where('company_id', $request->id)->get();

        Log::debug(":"."TEST_ABC:", [$contracts]);
        if($contracts->delivery_cycle === config('const.DELIVERY_CYCLE.ONECE_A_MONTH')){}
```

Comment: It should be `$contracts[0]->delivery_cycle`.